# Where is oneapi/mkl/rng/device.hpp in oneMKL?

Tags: intel, intel-oneapi

I saw this include in some sycl projects using `oneMKL` library and it is also used by other intel's libraries like dpct.

However browsing [oneMKL](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneMKL) source code I don't find this file under [oneapi/mkl/rng](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneMKL/tree/develop/include/oneapi/mkl/rng).
Where is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're on Linux:
/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/latest/include/oneapi/mkl/rng

on Windows:
c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\latest\include\oneapi\mkl\rng

Comment: Hello, I'm on Linux but I compiled oneMKL, oneTBB and so on myself because I'm using llvm clang++ to target NVidia GPUs. Is the version of oneMKL available on GitHub different from the one you're referring to?

Comment: No but on GitHub is just the interfaces. I’m referring to the oneAPI base toolkit installation.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However I don't want to install the base toolkit, I'm instead installing myself llvm, onetbb, onemkl, onedbb and so on. Essentially I don't want to use dpcpp as a compiler, so is there a way to get oneMKL as it is in the base toolkit ? I'm not sure I understand the difference between the open source version and the base toolkit

Comment: There is no open source version of MKL. Only the headers are open sourced, and they are used just to link to the libraries that are provided in the base toolkit. I understand you’re trying to compile against the Codeplay CUDA backend, and you might? Be able to do so, but for any MKL calls you should still link to MKL. On the oneMKL interface GitHub it is listed which backend to use when targeting NVIDIA GPUs. Have you tried that?  And/or what MKL calls are you trying to use?